# Is it possible to enable a marker from code?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-markers

It is possible to only run tests marked by a certain marker by using the `-m` argument when calling pytest.

e.g. `pytest -m testsubset_a`.

I wonder... Is it also possible to enable one of these markers from inside the code? e.g. somewhere during `pytest_collection_modifyitems()`?

The reason why I'm asking is because I'm working on a test-harnass that will use pytest markers to enable a specific subset of tests, but did not do so in the past. Since we want to be backwards compatible, I want to enable a default subset (marker) when no `-m` argument was given.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen That's not what I'm asking. I know you can add_marker to tests, we already do that in our code.
What I'm asking is if you can "enable" a marker (as if it was passed to pytest from the shell) from inside the code.

Comment: do you need an example illustrating this? and yes I am fairly certain this is possible with this hook

Comment: @gold_cy: If possible, sure. That'd be very helpful! But just to be clear: I'm not talking about `item.add_marker()`. I know how to do that.

Comment: @Opifex correct, you want to run only certain markers even if the person excludes the `-m` flag, is that the desired behavior?

Comment: @gold_cy Yes, so e.g. i have `marker_a` and `marker_b`; then the user can pass both of those as arguments to `-m`. However, if the user does not use `-m` it should default to `marker_a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the markers passed to `-m` from inside the code quite easily with `config.option.markerexpr`.

So... defaulting when no option was passed is as easy as

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config):
    if config.option.markerexpr == "":
        config.option.markerexpr = "mydefaultmarker"
```

Comment: if this works for you, then this is what you should go by, obviously the example I gave doesn't take in to account different types of scenarios. I deleted my other answer since it does not apply but glad you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: @gold_cy Actually I would have upvoted your answer (maybe after a small correction in the code example), because it was also useful information that was relevant. But the above code is a lot more straight-forward and less "hacky".

Comment: I would rather not confuse people coming to this page and trying to find a solution. I will upvote your answer as it solves the question at hand, making it more visible for future readers.

Comment: should it be `config.option.markerexpr = "mydefaultmarker"`?

Comment: @Jirka very likely, yes. It's surprising that no one has pointed that out before you. I will edit it.